# How to find the index of .First match?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, list, indexing, match

I'm using this:

```
foreach (var item in set)
{
    string matchingString = conLines.FirstOrDefault(r => (r.IndexOf(item.firstParam) >= 0 && r.IndexOf(item.secondParam) >= 0) && (r.IndexOf(item.firstParam) < r.IndexOf(item.secondParam)));
}
```

Where:

```
List<string> conLines = ...
```

And

```
public class className
{
    public string firstParam { get; set; }
    public string secondParam { get; set; }
}

    public static List<className> set = ....
```

And I want to know at which index of conLines that a matchingString was found.

At the end of the day, what I'm trying to do is search through conLines, string by string, for all matches with firstParam and secondParam (sequentially, in the same string of conLines). If a match is found, I want to change that string in conLines. Whether the line finds a match and gets changed or not, I want to print it out. So essentially I'm reading in conLines and printing it all out including changes in the lines that found a match for firstParam and secondParam.

Example:

if conLines were:

```
alpha beta dog cat
chair ramp table seat
blog journal article letter
```

and firstParam, secondParam included:

```
ramp, table
article, letter
```

and the changes I made were to add -01 to the matches, I would be printing out:

```
alpha beta dog cat
char ramp-01 table-01 seat
blog journal article-01 letter-01
```

Answer (score 4):

No matter how you find the index, it's going to be sub-optimal. You'll wind up enumerating the collection twice. Instead, you should either:

1. Use a `for` loop to loop over the collection (if possible). That way, whenever you find the fist match, you'll already have the index (only works if the collection exposes and indexer and a pre-calculated Length/Count property):

   ```
   for(var i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
   {
       if(collection[i] == query)
       {
           // You have the match with collection[i] and the index in i
       }
   }
   ```
2. Loop over the collection using `GetEnumerator` and count the index using a counter. This will work for any `IEnumerable`:

   ```
   var enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator();
   var count = 0;

   while(enumerator.MoveNext())
   {
       if(enumerator.Current == query)
       {
           // You have the match in enumerator.Current and the index in count
       }
       count++;
   }
   ```

Either way, you'll only have to loop over the collection a single time rather than twice (once for `FirstOrDefault` and then again to get the index.

Comment: If you have the time and don't mind, could you show me what you mean?

Comment: @user2340818 - Added examples.

Comment: Is there a reason you chose not to use a foreach loop in the second example?

Comment: @sWW - Nope. That would work just as well. Does the same thing behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using a `Select` at the front that includes the index:

```
var temp =  conLines.Select((l, i) => new {l, i})
                    .FirstOrDefault(r => (r.l.IndexOf(item.firstParam) >= 0 
                                       && r.l.IndexOf(item.secondParam) >= 0)
                                       && (r.l.IndexOf(item.firstParam) < r.l.IndexOf(item.secondParam)
                                   ));
string matchingString = temp.l;
int index = temp.i;
```

Although I'm struggling to figure out how you get the *output* you want.  Why do both lines have a '01'?

Comment: The output is kind of irrelevant. I'll be performing a method on the strings that find a match, but the method (in this example, adding -01 to the matches) isn't important to my question.